# Getting/Updating A Counter in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Architectural question. As part of a game, we were looking at keeping track of number of items that have been completed across all players. No problem keeping track of a players status, dynamo shards nicely across the users. But if I want a single number that shows how many of X have been processed, then I'm talking about a single row table, which means everyone who is updated and retrieving from that table is hitting on exactly the same row. I'm pretty sure Dynamo will take a lot of this, but I'm wondering how well it will scale. As each person performs a function, the counter would increment, and then they would read it back.

I'm thinking we could keep the counter in memcache or Redis, and update it when a new item is classified, and rebuild it on a nightly basis. This seems like overkill, and requires extra infrastructure.

Any thoughts? Has anyone done this successfully? Dynamo keeps track, but the number they return can be six hours out of date.

Comment: you're aware of [(strongly) consistent read](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/APISummary.html), right? from a high level, it's still not optimal for something accessed very frequently.

Comment: How much write and read throughput do you want from this counter? DynamoDB has support [for atomic increments and decrements](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters) .

Comment: It's a game, it's going to get some serious promotion, it's tough to tell what's good. It's the old question - how much do you prepare for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, a single item that is incremented by everyone will not scale well if you expect there to be more than 1000 writes per second (the number of writes available for a single partition). If you expect fewer than 1000 writes per second, DynamoDB does allow for strongly consistent reads on a single item (alternatively, you can also ask for the updated value to be returned in the result of the UpdateItem request)

Aggregating the counts in memcached or Redis and doing an "bulk" ADD (e.g. ADD 1000) to DynamoDB regularly would definitely help spread the accesses out over time and is probably the best approach if you need strong consistency, losing the cached data in the event of a crash is acceptable, and your availability requirements are low.

If you don't need strong consistency though (e.g. the count can be treated more as a lower bound) you could use write sharding to keep multiple counters to spread the accesses out such that each counter is expected to be accessed less than 1000 times per second.

Then you can aggregate the count periodically with either a Scan (if only a few small counts the scan shouldn't be expensive) or multiple GetItem calls. There is some discussion about this in these [slides](http://files.meetup.com/8763012/AWS_Meetup_DynamoDB_Yanacek_102413_FINAL_to%20post.pptx).

Alternatively, if you can use the preview region, you could enable DynamoDB Streams on the table and use an AWS Lambda function that takes batches of counts from the table stream and aggregates the counts into a subcount. Repeat the above to build a final count. This approach would allow a total count to be constantly aggregated rather than setting up a periodic scan activity.

Comment: I've been wondering about streaming. I think 1,000 writes per second would be a pretty crazy success, but what to do if we go past that. I don't really like the thought of trying to fix a successful game on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

The main question here is how fast do you really need to increment that number. We use [Atomic counters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters) as part of our production by using a global table across the system that is called "counters". We rarely need to increment more than a few times per second per counter so the scaling is not a problem at the moment.

It all comes down to the rate and number of counters you need to keep (and scale).

If you need very fast counters, I guess there are better approaches (such as in-memory cache / redis) with periodic flushes. I don't consider this an overkill if you need to prepare yourself for that scale.